# How to pack all linked data inside the current .blend file

Tags: rendering, linked-data

I'm working on an animated short. I am trying to send my final results to a render farm because I don't have the processing power to render it on my computer. Each shot is in a separate linked .blend file, and the render service cannot see the linked data. 
Note : All paths are relative and `File->External Data->Pack All Into .blend` doesn't do it

Is there a way to send a linked file as its own isolated .blend, with its own path data?

Comment: Not sure if it helps for linked files, but you could try `File`->`External Data`->`Pack All Into .blend`.

Comment: `File->External data->Make all paths relative` may also help. Are you sure all files are uploading? Naming the render farm may also help, do they not provide support?

Comment: The render farm is pixleplow.net. My paths are currently relative, and I can't pack the data in the linked files...

Comment: possible answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40020/does-anyone-know-how-to-successfully-pack-linked-objects-not-just-textures-int?lq=1

Answer (score 3):

There is now an add-on ([BlendFile Utils](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/BlendFile_Utils)) that comes with Blender (2.77 and newer).

That supports packing a file and all its dependencies into an archive.

---

Note that this is a stand-alone tool which can be run from the command line, the same code used on the Blender-Cloud for downloading blend's as zipfiles and was used for exporting Blend files to the renderfarm for the short film [Cosmos Laundromat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-rmzh0PI3c).

Comment: I have install and when export its giving error http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72581/file-missing-when-open-for-render

Comment: @atek, this is a bug, please report it in Blender's bug tracker.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is an old question, but it is somewhat unanswered: 
There is a hidden feature/operator called:
**"Pack Blender Libraries"**

It is not available in the UI, but you can access it by searching it with Spacebar search.

It will do exactly what you are looking for, pack all linked libraries into one file.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you tested this?

Comment: Except it doesn't pack anything in Blender 2.9 unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

I found that when I tried this, it did actually archive all the images I was using in the composite, however when I opened the .blend file it created and checked the image input nodes, they were not actually pointing to the archived images.

It's not an ideal solution either because files on our render farm are on a separate partition from the working files.

Unfortunately there is a different file structure between my local environment and the remote render farm so I'm not sure how to point to the files which are already in the remote location.  When I try and edit the note to write in the path where I know the files to exist blender won't let me save the node because on my local machine that path does not actually exist.

There must be some process for remote vs local file paths.