# Does anyone know how to successfully pack linked objects (not just textures) into a single .blend file?

Tags: rendering, linked-data

I have been trying to use SheepIt! render farm for a short animation. Unfortunatly, `File -> External Data -> Automatically pack into .blend` DOES NOT pack linked objects from other .blend files. SheepIt! gives a warning that those libary links are not in the file to process.

Does anyone know how to successfully pack linked objects (not just textures) into a single .blend file?

I know that this question has been asked by Louie:
[How to pack all linked data inside the current .blend file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/how-to-pack-all-linked-data-inside-the-current-blend-file).
Unfortunately he did not get a working soluion answer :-/

Comment: thank you very much Mr. Zak ... that did it :-) so I got a working file with the links and do a save as "Made Local" file for renderfarms

Answer (score 5):

To quickly get all the linked data in one .blend file you can use *Make Local* command.

[image]

1. Select all the objects which are linked (or simply <kbd>A</kbd> to select all).
2. Press <kbd>L</kbd> and select *All* option. This will make all the objects, their data, materials etc. stored locally in this file, so create a full copy (in the same way as [Append](http://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html?highlight=append) data, with only difference that you shouldn't search where to append from).

*Note that you may want to save these locally stored objects as a new file so only to send it to renderfarm and not ruin linking of your original file*.